# Как лучше парсить картинки с сайта в мое приложение?

Tags: android

Мне нужно из моего андроид приложения обратиться к сайту с картинками и разместить эти картинки у себя в приложении. Посоветуйте, как правильно построить ход работы, т.к. я совершенно не знаю, как это реализовать. Друг говорит, нужно писать парсер на php и заливать его на хостинг, при обращении к которому из моего андроид приложения, будут доставаться картинки с сайта. Но мне данный способ не нравится.

Есть у вас какие-нибудь предложения по поводу получения приложением картинок с сайта?
И еще, каким образом их можно разместить в приложении? Использовав ListView или есть еще варианты?

Comment: Парсить через сайт - хорошо. Если там поменяют html, Вам нужно будет только обновить свой сайт.

Но если парсить на клиенте, то можно посмотреть на jsoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Скрипт на php позволит в приложении только отображать картинки без нужды их выковыривания из сайта. К тому же не надо обновлять приложение при изменении источника картинок.
   С другой стороны, вы будете зависеть от хостера, писать часть кода на другом языке да и заботиться о возможной высокой нагрузке на сервер.
2. Если выковыривать картинки приложением - то ваш вариант - `jsoup` и никакой возни с php, сервером, хостером и нагрузками на него.
3. ListView устарел. Используйте `RecyclerView` - он из коробки умеет как вертикально списки показывать, так и горизонтально, так и сеткой.
4. Получив ссылки на картинки грузите/отображайте их спец. либами. UIL или Picasso

Comment: если использовать jsoup, он будет проверять изменения картинок на сайте? Т.е., если на сайте часть картинок уберут, в приложении отобразятся изменения?

Comment: @Crok, всё зависит от того, как вы код напишите. В общем - jsoup получает на вход HTML код страницы и вытаскивает оттуда ссылки на картинки. Того, чего нет, он вытащить не сможет. Т.е. да - удалённые картинки магическим образом нигде не появятся. Если вы их ссами не сохраните у себя в приложении.

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо, Вам, Юрий!!!